# Selecting element with jdom and jaxen

Tags: java, jdom

I have the following xml

```
   <administration xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema.xsd">
      <students>
           <student name = 'alpha' number='s1111111'>
              <grades>
                 <grade course='beta'> 1 </grade>
              </grades>
      </students>
   </administration>
```

And i use the following JDOM code, but it keeps returning null.

The `reader.root` refers to the root element of the document

```
 Element studentXmlElement = (org.jdom.Element) XPath.selectSingleNode(reader.root,    " administration/students/student[@number='s1111111']");
```

But as i said, the studentXmlElement is null once i return it.

Answer (score 1):

Few things : student tag is not closed and the xpath has a leading space. I assume it is by mistake.

Your xml has a namespace specified and your xpath selection does not include a namespace and prefix. 
Use *'xpath.addNamespace(java.lang.String prefix, java.lang.String uri)'* method to add a namespace to your xpath.

Note that your xml does not have any namespace prefix. 
In XPath, there is no such thing as a 'default namespace'. The empty prefix always resolves to the empty namespace URI.

Refer the API here for more details: http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/xpath/XPath.html#addNamespace%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: Thanks for the explaining answer, i looked into the api, but i am a bit confused, What exactly is the code i write right now without having a namespace prefix in the xml file.

Comment: Using this approach you can't extract without having a prefix. That's the 'Note: In XPath, there is no such thing as a 'default namespace'. The empty prefix always resolves to the empty namespace URI.' in the API implies.  Either use some prefix like xmlns:w3s in your xml in which case use can use addNameSpace method or remove the namespace (xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com") itself from xml in which case your current xpath extraction code will work.

Comment: I deleted the namespace from the xml, i tested it in some online xpath parser, but the C# just won't return anything.